# When I talk about my hobby, which one is the best option?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm talking about my hobby of fishing. Which one should I opt for and why?

> 1. I like going fishing
> 2. I like go fishing
> 3. I like to go to fishing

Comment: *None!* Go for - I *like fishing!*

Comment: Only the first is grammatical.  As MaulikV mentioned, though, *I like fishing* is shorter and easier to say.

Comment: *like* takes either infinitive or *-ing* form. So you can rephrase the first one as *I like to go fishing.*

Answer (score 1):

> I like fishing.
>
> I like going fishing.
>
> I like to go fishing.

These three are grammatically correct and interchangeable. Only "I like go fishing" is incorrect. As Ustanak pointed out, "*like* takes either an infinitive or an *-ing* form."

You can also use "enjoy" to replace "like" in some instances, except that it would be improper to say, "I enjoy to go fishing," as enjoy does ***not*** take the infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question

> What do you like to do in your spare time?

The standard answer is

> **I like to go fishing.**
>
> P1: What do you want to do today?
>   P2: How about let's **go fishing**?

One uses **go**, since fishing usually occurs at another location.

> We have a house about a mile from the lake.
>   We can **go fishing** there after dinner.

But if you're lucky

> Our house is right on the lake.
>   We can **fish** off the back porch. *( no need to go anywhere )*

Using **go** can also imply there are other activities around the fishing, an analogy would be driving

> I like **driving**
>   I like **to go driving**

have slightly different meanings.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just say **"My hobby is [fishing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fishing)"**?

- *Fishing* is the sport or job of catching fish: